# How to read a file outside of project directories with Scanner

Tags: java

I have this 2 lines in my code:

```
String csvPath = "D:\\myFolder";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(ReadCSV.class.getResourceAsStream(csvPath + "\\myFile.csv"));
```

It gets me a null pointer error. I think it is because it is trying to find it under project path. How can I make this work without omitting the scanner? Is it possible to make it work wit getResourceAsStream() ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Scanner` constructor taking a `File`:

```
String csvPath = "D:\\myFolder";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(csvPath, "myFile.csv"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanner class constructor always take input Stream object as an argument .

You can also try this way.

```
   File file=new File("D:/myFolder/myFile.csv");
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
   System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
```

Comment: This is a Windows machine, so it's better to use backslashes as path separators.

Answer (score 0):

The `getResourceAsStream` is used for resources within the class path and they always take '/' as path separator.

In your case, use a File as parameter as follows:

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\myFolder\\myfile.csv"));`

Should do.